# MySQL database limits

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using a solution with AWS+RDS, and I was wondering what are the absolute Database limits. Limits like

1. Number of rows in a table.
2. Number of tables in a database.
3. Number of databases in an RDS instance.

Comment: As far as MySQL itself is concerned, I think you will find this link useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limits.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of database instances: 20

[Request to Increase Amazon RDS DB Instance Allocation](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/request-to-increase-the-amazon-rds-db-instance-limit/)

> By default, customers are allowed to have up to a total of 20 Amazon
>   RDS DB instances. Of those 20, up to 10 can be Oracle DB Instances
>   under the "License Included" model. All 20 can be used for MySQL or
>   Oracle under the "BYOL" model.

Size limit per instance is 1 TB.

You can have [as many databases as you want](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=250823) on one instance.

Limits on MySQL depend on the storage engine:

- MyISAM are files, so it depends on how many files are allowed on the filesystem etc
- InnoDB has a maximum of two billion tables. I guess you run out of your 1 TB diskspace before filling those two billion tables ;) [Is there a maximum number of tables ?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,158,165)

Comment: I actually want to know the MySQL limits.

Comment: Are you sure that you can have as many databases as you want in an instance, I think the limit is 32,000 databases per Instance.

Comment: Well, thats what `Shlomo Swidler` said in the linked thread and he wasn't corrected by `Pavan@AWS` who joined the discussion later.